# What does 'DPkg::Options::=--force-confdef' do?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I'm reading [this blog post](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/ec2-userdata)

What does

```
-o DPkg::Options::=--force-confdef \
-o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold \
```

do?

Comment: Different title, but the duplicate I linked answers your question in detail